# ItemTouchHelper.Callback vs RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener

Tags: android

It seems to me that both can listen to RecyclerView's item and call back when a gesture is detected. What is the difference between them and which should I choose to use?

Answer (score 0):

`ItemTouchHelper.Callback` (abstract class) :

> This class is the contract between ItemTouchHelper and your
>   application. It lets you control which touch behaviors are enabled per
>   each ViewHolder and also receive callbacks when user performs these
>   actions......

`RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` (interface) :

> An OnItemTouchListener allows the application to intercept touch
>   events in progress at the view hierarchy level of the RecyclerView
>   before those touch events are considered for RecyclerView's own
>   scrolling behavior...

That seems quite self explantory, I'd read more into the docs on each class.  As for which one to use, that would depend on your usecase.  Do you need to intercept touch events BEFORE the RecyclerView knows about the touch event? If so `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` else `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`.  The method callbacks, and what they do would best decide which to use in most cases. There could also be many reasons why either could work for many usecases.